# How to screenshot a webpage in php?

Tags: php

I am currently making a website where I simply want users to be able to screenshot a webpage and then download the image. So what I need help with is: how do I screenshot a webpage using PHP then save the image on my server.

I have read a few other tutorials on how to screenshot a page, but I can't get it to work.

I am using a Linux server (Debian 7.0).

Comment: Can you include the code you've gone so far, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grabz.it](http://grabz.it)

---

**Take Website Screenshots with PHP**

1. Get your free [Application Key and Secret](http://grabz.it/login.aspx?action=create&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fgrabz.it%2fapi%2f%23Key).
2. Download the free [PHP Demo and Library](http://grabz.it/api/php/download.aspx) and try it out.

Then use it like this:

```
include("GrabzItClient.class.php");
$grabzIt = new GrabzItClient("APPLICATION KEY", "APPLICATION SECRET");
$grabzIt->SetImageOptions("http://www.google.com"); 
$grabzIt->SaveTo("google.jpg");
```

---

If you don't want to depend on 3rd parties, you can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html), i.e.:

```
phantomjs responsive-screenshot.js http://google.com
```

---

**Notes:**

1- Download  [responsive-screenshot.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ariya/phantomjs/master/examples/responsive-screenshot.js). Check the source code for available options.

2- You can install phantomjs by cloning the github repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that gives PHP access to a browser. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

Like previous answers the project relies on PhantomJS.

After downloading and setup you would simply use the following code:

```
$myUrl          = "http://www.google.com";
$windowObj      = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getBrowser('phantomjs')->getNewWindow($myUrl);

//now do a screenshot, valid formats are png, jpeg, gif.
$imageData      = $windowObj->screenshot("png");

file_put_contents("/path/to/your/file.png", $imageData);
```